# WPF/XAML Error using ResourceDictionary in App.xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I'm having trouble referencing a xaml resource dictionary file, leading to a runtime error saying 'resource x can't be found' when referring to a ResourceDictionary inside of . But using the Window.Resources node instead works.

working code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\Template_1.xaml">
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

my malfunctioning code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\Template_1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

My problem is I need the dictionary in application scope.
I'm accessing it as StaticResource and the build action of Template_1 is set as 'Page'

Any suggestions?

**Edit:
this is the structure of Template_1.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:self="clr-namespace:Application_1"
                >
<ControlTemplate x:Key="dict_TabContent" x:Shared="true" >
    <DockPanel>
        ...
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: I doubt using `<ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Template_1.xaml"/>` will make a difference, but can you show the <Application x:Class and <ResourceDictionary x:Class lines from your app.xaml and template_1.xaml files?  Are you using x:ClassModifier anywhere?

Comment: Can you please post the xaml of the resource that can not be resolved from Template_1.xaml

Comment: added the structure to the question. thank you for having a look

Comment: Have you tried to set x:Shared="false" auf dict_TabContent in the Application Resource Scenario?

Comment: Yes I tried it :( I'm rebuilding my project from scratch and so far it is working (yet some work to do)

Comment: Have you tried to switch from `\ ` to `/`? Because https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742451(v=vs.100).aspx mentions that a backslash could be interpreted as escape character.

Comment: It was worth a try but sadly it didn't solve the problem

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the WPF project is not the startup project of my solution. And I'm using an overloaded constructor. I just found out about Pack URIs and going to have a try with that.

Comment: Pack URIs are not solving the issue. The Problem seems to be the non-wpf startup project (project a). Do I need to add a reference from project a to the wpf project through properties->Resources? And if so, how exactly does it work? As 'String', 'File' or 'Other'?

Comment: I did some more testing and I think App.xaml and the code-behind never gets processed in the first place. For testing I added a MessageBox to the Application_Startup method. The MessageBox never shows up (Startup="Application_Startup" is set accordingly)

Comment: Take a look at this site: http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/05/managing-application-resources-when-wpf-is-hosted/ - Maybe it helps you to solve your Problem. - Do I asume right that your Host Application is a Windows Forms Application?

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitively have a read later on. Though I managed to get rid of the problem in the original sln by some dirty code behind inside the application derivate (overriding OnStartup and creating a ResourceDictionary object)